# Oracle XE 11.2.0 data pump expdb works on but impdb doesn't on Windows 10

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-xe, impdp, datapump

New to Oracle DB administration here. I have a fresh localhost installation of Oracle XE 11.2.0 (x64 installation from [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-prior-releases.html)) on my computer using Windows 10 64-bit.

I am able to connect to the DB using both DataGrip using `SYS as SYSDBA` user and I am able to connect using `sqlplus` command-line tool. I typed an `admin` password on installation but somehow I am able to connect using `sys` password `sqlplus sys/sys as sysdba` (as I said, I am an Oracle DB rookie).

I have to import an exported `EXP.DMP` file from a colleague using the following command:

```
impdp.exe 'sys/sys as sysdba' FULL=Y DUMPFILE=exp.dmp REUSE_DATAFILES=Y TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE
```

Windows starts to complain:

[image]

And the following line appears in the command line:

```
c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin>impdp.exe 'sys/sys as sysdba' FULL=Y DUMPFILE=exp2.dmp REUSE_DATAFILES=Y TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE
Access is denied.

c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin>
```

**Important note:** I have tried to **export** instead to `exp2.dmp` in order to try another command and it works with no issue:

```
c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin>expdp.exe 'sys/sys as sysdba' FULL=Y DUMPFILE=exp2.dmp directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR logfile=exp.log

Export: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Tue Mar 9 14:41:51 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Starting "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_FULL_01":  "sys/******** AS SYSDBA" FULL=Y DUMPFILE=exp2.dmp directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR logfile=exp.log
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 161.2 MB
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/TABLESPACE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/PROFILE
... omitted ...
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/AUDIT
. . exported "APEX_040000"."WWV_FLOW_PAGE_PLUGS"         27.16 MB   38892 rows
... omitted ...
. . exported "SYSTEM"."SQLPLUS_PRODUCT_PROFILE"              0 KB       0 rows
Master table "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for SYS.SYS_EXPORT_FULL_01 is:
  C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ADMIN\XE\DPDUMP\EXP2.DMP
Job "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_FULL_01" successfully completed at 14:42:55


c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin>
```

---

How to make the import successful?

**Edit:** I have noticed something very odd in the `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin` folder. I have installed the database engine using `setup.exe` and everything went smoothly. What's going on? Can I download the file anywhere for 11.2.0 XE without the un/installing again which would take another hour?

[image]

Comment: I've never seen that windows pop-up error, and cannot imagine it happening from a command-line interface.  I will say that you should not be running exp/imp/expdp/impdp as user SYS. The documentation is very consistent across all versions: "Do not invoke Export as SYSDBA, except at the request of Oracle technical support. SYSDBA is used internally and has specialized functions; its behavior is not the same as for general user"

Comment: " but somehow I am able to connect using sys password sqlplus sys/sys as sysdba"  It is using OS authentication - ignoring the username/password and allowing you in because your OS account is a member of the OS group 'DBA'.  It does this because you specified "as sysdba", which connects you as use SYS.  This only applies with local (non-network) connections.  It uses the env variable ORACLE_SID to designate _which_ database (there could be > 1) to connect to.

Comment: @EdStevens: Thanks for the comments. Please, check out my edit. The `impdb.exe` file has somehow `0kB` after installation.

Comment: It looks like you accidentally overwrote impdb.exe since it is 0kB and has today's date. Can you restore it to a previous version from a backup?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, so reinstalling should help (I have no idea about restoring these exe files, cannot find relevant documentation). I just wonder, how is it possible it was overwritten? Executing `impdb.exe` doesn't modify itself, or does?